# CSS <html> / <body> font-size set in vw, user tries to zoom website

Tags: html, css, viewport, font-size

I created a website page with some background images and text overlay-ed in specific regions, and aligned them by setting all the length measurements in vw.

It scales well on a mobile screen, but not on a desktop. The first person I showed it to, tried to zoom out on a desktop, but because everything is relative to the viewport width, nothing appears to ever changes size.

I have many text boxes and images aligned, so how does one convert this design (where the font size depends on the width of its container), to something zoomable?

Created demo code, in the the actual code, the text lines up exactly with an intricate background, some times it is too big, so to see more in one go, the user wishes to zoom out:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
        <style>
            * {
                font-size:  inherit;
                padding:    0;
                margin:     0;
            }
    
            html {font-size: 2vw;}    /* Setting the html tag also changes the rem size */
            body {font-size: 1rem;}   /* 1rem now = 2vw, for clarity only, already inherited the same value */
    
            .container {
                position: relative;
                margin: 1em auto;
                width: 97vw;
            }
    
            #background_image {
                position: absolute;
                width:  100%;
            }
    
            /* text boxes aligned over image */
            .left  { left:   30vw; }
            .right { left:  60vw; }
            #div1  { top:    5vw; height: 10vw;}
            #div2  { top:   26vw; height: 10vw;}
            #div3  { top:   23vw; height: 10vw;}
    
            .text-box {
                position: absolute;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=container>
            <img id = "background_image" src="https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Test/xhtml-print/20050519/tests/jpeg420exif.jpg">
            <div id="div1" class="text-box  left">div1 text text test</div>
            <div id="div2" class="text-box  left">div1 text text test</div>
            <div id="div3" class="text-box right">div1 text text test</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: For anyone else, I ended up having to figure out some javascript, the answer is: added the following script to set the font size at page load, and scale everything according to a rem: var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;        
        document.getElementById("html").style.fontSize = width/49.12+"px";